# How to handle lat long values using boost?

Tags: c++, boost, coordinates, latitude-longitude, boost-geometry

In my application I receive latitude/longitude inputs in the following form: "N48 E010", "N40 E020", "S30 W110" ... 
What I am looking forward to do is check wether these points form a valid polygon or not.
My intent is to use the boost library to achieve my goal. So, I need help to:

1. Is there a type already defined to store a lat lon pair?
2. With a polygon already filled with the points, how to check if this is a valid polygon?
3. If the polygon is valid. How to get its area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be valid, a polygon needs to be closed, i.e. the last point must be the same as the first.
Since the smallest polygon is a triangle with 3 points, a valid polygon must have at least 4.
That's a simple enough test for you to do yourself.

The [boost geometry](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html) library has types defined to store lat lon pairs and can find the area of a polygon in geographic coordinates, see: [area](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/area/area_2_with_strategy.html).

Note: your latitude/longitude points are not in a standard form such as [ISO 6709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709) where latitude and longitude coordinates are represented as decimal numbers with North and East positive, South and West negative.
Therefore, you'll need to parse the coordinates into decimal numbers to use the boost library.

Also, be aware that many GIS libraries (including boost geometry) take coordinates in longitude/latitude order, to conform with [OGC](http://www.opengeospatial.org/docs/is) and [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) standards.